# When I update the same row in a table in SQL more than once, it gives an ORA-00001: unique constraint error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update a row in a table in SQL back to back and am getting an error when running the second update statement.

```
update employees 
set department_id = 50
where employee_id = 100;

update employees 
set department_id = 60
where employee_id = 100;
```

I'm getting an error in the second update statement.

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.JHIST_EMP_ID_ST_DATE_PK) violated
> ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.ADD_JOB_HISTORY", line 10
> ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY", line 2
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN.UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY'

I was expecting employee_id 100 to be assigned to department_id 60 after the second update.

I am not trying to insert a new record, just trying to update an existing one, so why is there a unique constraint error.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to wait with the second update until the *next* day. Apparently only one update per record and day is premitted in the history table.

Comment: Does committing in between updates really make any difference? Your question title suggests it does.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson you are right, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you aren't doing anything wrong (according to `update` statements you posted), but it is the `UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY` **database trigger** which does something *in the background*.

Check its code; looks like it calls a procedure (`update_job_history`) which calls yet another one (`add_job_history`), and it violated `JHIST_EMP_ID_ST_DATE_PK` primary key constraint in line #10.